# How to track changes in a list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to track any changes made to a list for my app, such that it is easier to revert back to any of the previous states of that list.

I could just create another list in and record the changes of the list I am tracking in it:

```dart
List<List<int>> tracker_list = [];
List<int> tracked_list = [];

tracked_list.add(1); /*this will be called over and over again, eventually making 
tracker_list a very large variable and it will be difficult to get previous states of tracked_list.*/

if(tracked_list != tracker_list[tracker_list.length - 1]) tracker_list.add(tracked_list);
```

but it won't be easy to revert back to a state of that list and will be inefficient and use
up alot of ram.

Is there any easier solution to achieve it??

Comment: when anything changes in your list add a 3 item tuple: 1.operation type (add/del/update) 2. index 3. the value (new value for add / deleted value for del / new value for update) - then you will be able to go to the previous list incarnation

Comment: @pstink can u pls elaborate more on what u r trying to say, perhaps in a answer?

Comment: for example the list is `['foo', 'bar']` and you insert a new item `'foo1'` in index `1` so the list is now `['foo', 'foo1', 'bar']` then push a tuple with the info that you added a new item at index `1` so when reverting you can just delete an item from index `1` and the list is back `['foo', 'bar']` - similar stuff should be done when deleting / updating the list

Comment: @psink i've implemented it and it is quite easy to... please post it in a answer so i can mark it as the correct one

Comment: oh come on, write a self answer then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example the list is ['foo', 'bar'] and you insert a new item 'foo1' in index 1 so the list is now ['foo', 'foo1', 'bar'] then push a tuple with the info that you added a new item at index 1 so when reverting you can just delete an item from index 1 and the list is back ['foo', 'bar'] - similar stuff should be done when deleting / updating the list

-written by @psink in the comments below the question